# Check if iTunes Match is enabled on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to programatically verify if iTunes Match is enabled on a device? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

The use case here is that I want to log how many of my users are on match, so that I can prioritize features for my app accordingly, since some of them don't work too well with match today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't learn because this is the users private settings